# How best to ensure my question will not "get migrated" to World Building?

Tags: support

I've just asked a question [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/15320/12102) that is at the edge of the on-topic envelope. I don't want it to "get migrated" to *World Building* because then (I think) I would have to join in order to regain control and then delete it and then un-join *World Building*. Besides writing this question, is there any way I can try to ensure that this doesnt't happen?

It seems that [involuntary, sudden migration can be done to your question at any time](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/751/12102), I'd like some kind of lock - *at least* to sites where I'm not even a member. Is this possible?

Comment: Also, right now the only close vote on it is a "too broad" vote, not an "off topic" vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't prevent your question from getting migrated. The best way would be to simply make sure the question is reasonable from the start, and defend if someone things it should be migrated.

Comment: Furthermore, uhoh, since you have made your desire clear, we (the mods) can avoid migrating until the community makes a decision. If your question gets to four close votes and you are worried it will be migrated, you can delete it if you want.

Comment: That's good common sense advice. I'm really asking about migration that could happen suddenly without discussion, where there is no opportunity to defend - and also I'm trying to type on a phone right now which is clearly a mistake! Anyway my previous migration happened fairly suddenly. It was done for the most benevolent of reasons, but if there were close votes they either happened in the eight hours when I was asleep, or somehow I didn't spot them.

Comment: A moderator has to migrate the question. Unfortunately there isn't a whole lot that you can done...

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto Users over 3000 rep can vote to migrate to a select number of sites.

Comment: @uhoh Instant migrations only happen by mods.

Comment: Which for a beta site is only to meta.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto Right, but I have seen questions migrated to meta before in lieu of being able to migrate them elsewhere.