# Request for cleanup: There's only one space in SpaceX!

Tags: discussion

Sorry. This just really irritates me: but SpaceX is a single word! There is, ironically, no space between the Space and the X. Neither is there a hyphen or any other type of dash! As an example:

```
+--------------+-------------+
| Good Example | Bad Example |
+--------------+-------------+
| SpaceX       | Space X     |
|              | Space-X     |
+--------------+-------------+
```

I've been slowly working through some of the questions and answers with the search term `"space x"` and eliminating the worst offenders. But there's quite a few. Anyone willing to lend a hand? :)

<sup>I also casually request fellow janitors to use the edit summary of "there's no space in SpaceX" when relevant... :P</sup>

Comment: Editing is good. Making SE better is good. Kudos for the effort. But *Sorry. This just really irritates me* is not a good way to approach SE. With thousands of users, if everyone starts talking about what "rubs them the wrong way" or irritates them, it will be a mess. It being OK if only "senior people" or high rep users get to talk about what bothers them is also counter to what makes SE work so well.

Comment: I think being overly serious is also not a desirable trait for SE. This is meant as a light hearted request for help in cleaning a few minor things up. No need to read into it so deeply. In fact, this is exactly the reason I avoid SE meta sites: it's far too argumentative and it's very off-putting, to the point where I usually don't want to bother. So, it works both ways. In fact, I'm amazed someone managed to take offence to this.

Comment: What is "light hearted" about "This just really irritates me"?

Comment: If the joke at the end, the ":P", and the ":)" weren't enough to provide a sense of tone for that message, I apologise — I literally went out of my way to try and make this light-hearted. But frankly, yeah, I'm done with SE meta already. cya.

Comment: My eyes are getting on in years and I'm too cheap to buy glasses, so I missed the fine print at the bottom of the question. I also tried to [add humor to a meta question once](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/751/#comment3164_755) and it didn't produce the expected results with all users. I guess SXSE meta is not as chatty as other SE meta sites, but if you have questions about the site or see something else that needs attention or could possibly be improved, it works great!

Comment: Perhaps noteworthy is that their website is spacex.com. Space-x.com is a dead end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Agree. I've been searching (With quotations) "Space X", and found many candidates, which I have fixed. There's no doubt a few more, but it takes a while for the search to update. I think the few remaining items are clear.

Also, if you should come across these, feel free to clean up some of those same articles. Many of the same people who use "Space X" can also use a good copy edit.