# Why is @KimHolder's hat bigger than mine?

Tags: discussion

(tongue planted firmly in cheek)

I think it's incredibly unfair that @KimHolder gets to have a bigger hat than I do. I have more rep, shouldn't it be *me* that get's the bigger hat?

Is it because she's on the radio, or building a Moon base, or has her own chat channel?

Or is someone suggesting I have small hands? :-)

I scrolled down the list of questions until I found an adjacent pair so I could check them side-by-side. Sure enough, her *Some Kind of Sun Thingy* is bigger than my *Some Kind of Sun Thingy!* (this is the actual SE term for the hat).

I think an SE site should be flat, and not show such favoritism. The idea that there is an elite class of SXSE users that can show big hats is counter to all that SE stands for.

I say Equality and Justice All (hats)!

*Happy Holidays!*

> $\hspace{6.5cm}$[image]

Comment: There may in fact be a way to adjust hat size. I've been trying different strategies with my MacBook trackpad but so far no luck.

Comment: It's because we like her more than you;-)

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto Indeed. I guess that there are still some things in life that can't be done with Python. I thought it would solve all of life's challenges.

Comment: Wow, look at that... I did not even ever see this until now. I'm really slipping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a resize icon on hats. Grab the top red control handle (For rotating) and move straight up.  Or down to resize.

There is a tick box "Show Controls" to activate the controls.
[image: Hat controls]

Comment: I remember using something like that last year, but this year I don't know how to make the control appear; https://i.stack.imgur.com/E90bz.jpg

Comment: Got it, thanks! Maybe I have [put off getting glasses](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/930/#comment3677_930) long enough.