# Two SpaceX Dragon tags, is clarification needed?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

In the question [What is SpaceX's parachute problem that NASA is concerned about in the NASA ASAP report?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32166/12102) I needed a Dragon capsule tag. There are two to choose from:

[dragon](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon) and [dragon-v2](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-v2)

---

Do we need two tags? If so are these names and descriptions ideal, or could they benefit from a "tune-up"?

### dragon

**Excerpt:**

> Capsule for cargo and manned (eventually) payloads to orbit. Built by SpaceX, launched on a Falcon 9 rocket.

**Wiki:**

> The [Dragon capsule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_%28spacecraft%29) is produced by Space Explorations Technologies of California. Designed to launch on a Falcon 9 capsule, it was initially used in cargo mode, delivering payloads to the ISS. Recovery is by parachute into the ocean.
>
> A second model, that incorporates pusher abort engines (Super Draco) will be used for manned flight. When not needed for abort usage, the Super Draco engines are designed to be used for a propulsive touchdown on land.

---

### dragon-v2:

**Excerpt:**

> SpaceX's second version of the Dragon spacecraft, also called "Crew Dragon". It is designed to carry humans.

**Wiki:**

> [None]

Comment: Completed, not exactly according to the accepted answer, but resolved nevertheless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where the constantly changing names of SpaceX's spacecraft is difficult... Right now there are 3 variants, and 4 uses that could be valid:

1. [dragon](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon)- The original dragon. Also could be all Dragon spacecraft.
2. [dragon-2](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-2)- The second generation of Dragons. This is composed of both a cargo and a crew Dragon version.
3. [crew-dragon](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crew-dragon)- This should be for anything related to crew dragon.
4. [cargo-dragon](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cargo-dragon)- This specifically refers to the second Cargo dragon, but I guess could be included for the first as well?

There are also a few synonyms, [dragonrider](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragonrider) which should go to [crew-dragon](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crew-dragon), and [dragon-v2](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-v2) and [dragon2](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon2), both of which I think should go to [dragon-2](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-2). All of the dragon 2 tagged questions should be evaluated for the crew/cargo dragon tags as well.

It's a bet of a mess, but... I'm going to remove a few of the synonyms to make this a bit easier for now, and then we can retag things appropriately. What do you think?

Comment: Icann bairly sepll synomyns, much less know what to do with them. Thank you for looking in to this, *I suspect* you will do the right thing. ;-) The only problem is if this interferes with @geoffc badge-getting somehow. I suppose he'll chime in if that's the case.

Comment: I mean, if someone were to propose these changes before I get to it they could get a badge, and I'm not likely to do so for at least a few hours...

Comment: Then we can consider "badge-man" geoffc and everyone else to be on notice. I don't really understand what badges are for, being so preoccupied by [hat envy](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/932/12102).

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto Was this ever completed?

Comment: It seems like dragon-v2 and crew-dragon are the tags that are used, I think that's okay.